# Symfony2 - how to register global event listener between Bundles

Tags: symfony

I got two Bundles:

- SenderBundle
- ReceiverBundle

First makes some action and dispatch an Event, let's say, `something.done`. Now I want to receive this Event and handle it in ReceiverBundle which contains listeners and proper actions assigned to it. I don't want to `$eventDispatcher->addListener()` in SenderBundle of course! But I want to register listeners for defined Events automatically!

I figured out to create a `services.xml` in ReceiverBundle with:

```
<services>
    <service id="some_listener" class="My\ReceiverBundle\Class">
        <tag name="kernel.event_handler" event="something.done" method="onSomethingDone" />
    </service>
</services>
```

Which is autoloaded with DependencyInjection.

I figured out it's something like working... but no. What I managed - Listener is registered after Event was sent. Why?!

I can see my Events in debug toolbar in Events as "Listeners not called". I guess it's because Listener is initiated and registered after Event was sent.

How to register Listener working with my other Bundle? It's made in some way in Doctrine (doctrine.event_listener) but I can't figure out how it's done. : /

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use the `kernel.event_listener` tag instead:

```
<services>
    <service id="some_listener" class="My\ReceiverBundle\Class">
        <tag name="kernel.event_listener" event="something.done" method="onSomethingDone" />
    </service>
</services>
```